# How to fire event on child click section in expandable list view in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In expandble list on a parent click, I have a child in which I have 3 text view and i want to fire different event when i click different textviews for example.

```
for text view 1 output is hello
for text view 2 output is hi
for text view 3 output is heya
```

Comment: please provide details what you have done till??

Answer (score 2):

```
ExpandableListView expandableListView; 
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

//////////////////////////Change your child text values here.


                return false;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

as edwin said you can make a costum adapter. In which you can setOnClickListner() method on each View. like I did in here..

```
   class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Contact>
  {
     LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    public CustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
     ArrayList<Contact> strings) {

      //let android do the initializing :)
  super(context, textViewResourceId, strings);
  }


        //class for caching the views in a row  
   private class ViewHolder
   {

    TextView id,name,phn_no;

   }

   ViewHolder viewHolder;

   @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if(convertView==null)
    {        
                                 //inflate the custom layout                        
     convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, null);
     viewHolder=new ViewHolder();

     //cache the views
     viewHolder.id=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_id_txt);
     viewHolder.name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_name_txt);
     viewHolder.phn_no=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.contact_ph_no_txt);
     viewHolder.id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hi!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }); 
     viewHolder.name.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Hello!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
     viewHolder.phn_no.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Heya!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();      
        }
    });

     //link the cached views to the convertview
     convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }
    else
     viewHolder=(ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
       //set the data to be displayed
       viewHolder.id.setText(contacts.get(position).get_id()+"");
    viewHolder.name.setText(contacts.get(position).get_name());
    viewHolder.phn_no.setText(contacts.get(position).get_phn_no());

    //return the view to be displayed
   return convertView;
   }

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try out this way:

> ```
> public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
> {
>     if (convertView == null) 
>     {
>         LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>         convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, null);
>     }       
>     tv_ChildFieldId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
>     tv_ChildFieldId.setText(getChildIdFromDB(groupPosition, childPosition).toString());
> tv_ChildFieldId.setOnClickListener(new ID_OnClickListener());
>     //And so on   
>     return convertView;
> }
> /**Onclick Listener for the Textview*/
> private class ID_OnClickListener implements OnClickListener
> {
>     @Override
>     public void onClick(View v) 
>     {
>     }
> });
> ```

Comment: Can i know what i the "tv_ChildFieldId" variable and its use? Im unable to decode its use. Thanks

Comment: It already shows in code if you can notice that carefully. Its `TextView` and its just added to show the details on screen.

Answer (score 0):

So you must create **Custom adapter** for expandable list . Then implement the `onClickListener` for your different widgets  interface in Custom adapter class

In your Custom adapter class

```
 @Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.child_layout, null);
    }
   //Give your On click Implementations Here
    return convertView;
}
```

Go Through [This](http://androidword.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-use-expandablelistview.html) and [this](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/)

The implement your **activity** with `OnChildClickListener`

```
@Override
public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
   int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Clicked On Child",
     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return true; //or false
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look [here](http://shenhengbin.wordpress.com/2012/03/25/android-practice-custom-expandablelistview-sample-2/)
You can define your custom expandable adapter that have

```
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Inside this method you can determine child position at relative to parent and set oc click listener you want

Answer (score 0):

Method from @edwin above failed! Implementing the **ExpandableListView.onchildItemClick** in activity doesn't give any calls.

The issue appears speacially if you have a custom and complicated ChildView.

For me it worked by setting a  **onclickListener** on the ***convertView*** itself. I get perfect clicks from inside the adapter.

```
convertView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(_context, groupPosition + " clicked "
                    + childPosition, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
```

**Make sure you write that outside the**

```
if(convertView==null){.....layout inflation}
```

parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help

```
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int     groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
   if (groupPosition == 0){
       if (childPosition == 0){
           Intent intent = new Intent(MarketJaipur.this, ClothesMarket.class);
           startActivity(intent);
       }
   }
        return false;
    }
});
```